Clearest sky month in Pyrenees
I’m thinking of visiting the Pic du Midi observatory, in the Pyrenees.  What time of year is statistically likely to have the clearest skies?

Don't they place observatories to have a good all-year-round viewing ability?

What did they say when you asked them?

...and in that FAQ is "The weather can be pure and clear in winter and summer."
